# Passing file path with spaces and forward slashes as argument to TCL command

Tags: command-line, tcl

I have a TCL script that is run by Libero using a file path provided as an argument to open a project. The file path is `C:\Users\me\Documents\FPGA projects\file.prjx`

I am running the script according to [Libero TCL Reference Guide](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/132972-libero-soc-tcl-commands-reference-guide) (pages 51 - 52) to run the script on the command line. On page 47, the doc outlines how to work with filenames with spaces; using braces or in the case where it is used as an argument use double quotes.

The command I am trying to execute is:

```
Path\to\libero SCRIPT:export.tcl SCRIPT_ARGS:""C:\Users\me\Documents\FPGA projects\file.prjx""
```

The outer set of double quotes is to follow the syntax outlined in page 52 of the document for providing arguments and the inner set of double quotes is to handle the white space in the first argument. I had expected `$argv 0` to be `C:\Users\me\Documents\FPGA projects\file.prjx`, but instead `$argv 0` is actually `C:\Users\me\Documents\FPGA`.

I added a print statement to the script to print `$argv`:

```
puts $argv
```

This gives a result of `C:\Users\me\Documents\FPGA` so the rest of the file path is not being interpreted as even being a second argument.

My assumption is that the conventions outlined in the document are just standard TCL conventions for providing a file path containing forward slashes and spaces as an argument. I have not been able to find an example of passing a similarly formatted argument in TCL. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with microsemi, but maybe you could try `SCRIPT_ARGS:"{filepath}"` or `SCRIPT_ARGS:"\"filepath\""`. I'm guessing the command line might be getting confused by the immediate close quote after the open quote.

Comment: Same here, I'd also give a try to: `SCRIPT_ARGS:"{\pa th\to\file} arg2 arg3"`

Comment: @Jerry the braces resulted in just an empty string as the argument, but the backslash escaped double quote did the trick!

Comment: I would try `{SCRIPT_ARGS:"C:\Users\me\Documents\FPGA projects\file.prjx"}` where the outer braces are Tcl's single quoting mechanism, and the inner quotes will be passed on to the libero command.

Comment: @glennjackman it looks like using the outer braces results in no arguments in `argv` just like the inner braces

Comment: Oh, lovely. Trying to force a piece of software to pass useful arguments over when said arguments contain a space (and who knows exactly what is going on with the processing of those arguments). Does changing the doubled-up `""` to single `"` work? If not, the simplest workaround may be to just move things into a directory whose pathname doesn't contain a space.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's the same issue but, having MagicSplat tclsh.exe and wish.exe linked to *.tcl and *.tk files in Windows (7 to 11), calling scripts this way:

```
processDIR.tcl "c:\My directory\subdir"
```

evals arguments only till first space, becoming `"c:\My"` BUT calling scripts like this:

```
tclsh.exe processDIR.tcl "c:\My directory\subdir"
```

trespasses complete argument.

Could you give it a try?

Comment: BTW I would say it's a bug but I haven't registered it at MagicSplat